# Android Source Code Plug-in

Tags: android

I've been using an eclipse plugin that allows me to view android source code for up to android 2.2. I recently cleared my eclipse folder and copied a fresh instance, thereby loosing the plug-in. I don't seem to remember what the plug-in was called and where I installed it from.

I'm not looking for downloading and building the entire source tree of android. This plug-in would allow me to step into android sources when I wanted.

Does anyone have a link to this plug-in location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably mean [`adt-addons`](http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/) project. The direct link to plugin you're searching is:  http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update/

Comment: This is it. Thanks. Would you know how this is different from downloading the sources from git and setting the .jar source location to the downloaded path? I see a lot of blogs out there with complicated instructions as opposed to this plug-in and it's supposed to have 4.0 sources as well.

Comment: This is exactly this. It just takes time to download all source code yourself, than make a jar using some script and then setup each platform of SDK in some specific way. Oh, and you should get correct source code version for different SDK Levels. It's just takes too much time...

Comment: A fantastic add-on everyone should use.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of your android-ver.jar you can set the location of the sources. I think it is enough to download only frameworks project of the AOSP to attach it as a source of a android.jar library.